# Array of states within context partially not updating

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, local-storage, react-context

So I'm new to Next.js/React and I'm running into a weird state thing and I think it's cause I don't really understand fully what's happening (or it's something super simple and I'm missing something super obvious).

The idea is that I have a player object that has a lot of different components. Each of these components can change individually and so I thought instead of creating one large player object state, I'll create a player object where each key is its own state. Additionally, I want the state to stay on reload and so I need to do some local storage. I tried to make a minimal working example to try and see and I'm getting the same problem.

So I have a `context.js` file which is basically a wrapper for my context:

```js
'use client'
import { createContext, useContext } from "react";
import { getPlayerStates } from "./defaultPlayerData";

const DataContext = createContext("{}");

export function DataWrapper({children}) {
    let playerStates = getPlayerStates();

    return (
        <DataContext.Provider value={{playerStates}}>
            {children}
        </DataContext.Provider>
    )
}

export function useDataContext() {
    return useContext(DataContext);
}

export function GetPlayerData() {
    const {playerStates} = useDataContext();
    return playerStates;
}
```

As you can see, I'm using a context provider to create a context which will store the player data. The `getPlayerStates` function is the one that actually creates the individual states:

```js
import { useLocalStorageNumber } from "./localStorage";

export function GetPlayerStates() {
    const [ener, setEner] = useLocalStorageNumber('energy', 0);
    const [eI, setEI] = useLocalStorageNumber('extraInfo', 0);
    return {
        'energy' : [ener, setEner],
        'extraInfo': [eI, setEi],
        // a lot more properties. Shortened it to make MWE
    }
}

export function updatePlayerData(playerData, playerStates) {
    const playerExists = (playerData && Object.keys(playerData).length > 0)
    if (playerExists) {
        playerStates['energy'][1](playerData.energy);
    }
}
```

As I said, I need to do everything through local storage because I want to refresh and keep the data. So the local storage file looks like this:

```js
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export function useLocalStorageNumber(key, fallbackValue) {
    var fbV = fallbackValue.toString()
    const [value, setValue] = useState(fbV);
    
    useEffect(() => {
        const stored = localStorage.getItem(key);
        if(stored) {
            var x = JSON.parse(stored)
            if (x != value ){
                setValue(x); //
            }
        } else {
            setValue(fbV);
        }   
    }, [fbV, key]);

    useEffect(() => {
        localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(value)); //
    }, [key, value]);

    return [value, setValue];
}
```

So this is where the main state for this individual item will be. So far so good. One last set of functions before I show what I'm outputting. This function is used to grabbing the appropriate keys and adding them into an array which will be returned for the main page.

```js
import { GetPlayerData } from "./context";
import { useLocalStorageNumber } from "./localStorage";

export default function CreateStatesForData(data) {
    const playerStates = GetPlayerData();

    var dataObj = {}
    for (var col of data) {
        for (var k of col) {
            if (k in playerStates) {
                var dataState = playerStates[k]
            }
            dataObj[k] = dataState
        }
    }
    return dataObj
}
```

Now I make the `page.js` file to actually display things:

```js
"use client"
import { GetPlayerData} from '@/helpers/context';
import CreateStatesForData from '@/helpers/stateForData';

export default function Page() {
  // Set data required (from playerData)
  var infoRequired = [["energy"]]
  var infoData = CreateStatesForData(infoRequired)

  // Set extra required (not from playerData)
  var extraRequired = [["extraInfo"]]
  var extraData = CreateStatesForData(extraRequired)

  // Helper function - Needed in every isntance (makes code easier to read too)
  function v(key) {
    if (key in infoData) {
      var x = infoData[key][0] 
    } else if (key in extraData) {
      var x = extraData[key][0]
    }
    return x
  }

  var Epow = v("energy")
  

  return (
    <>
        {Epow}
    </>
  )
}
```

I also have an uploader to actually upload the data:

```js
'use client'
import React, { useRef } from 'react';
import { GetPlayerStates, updatePlayerData } from '@/helpers/defaultPlayerData';

const ImportSaveForm = (props) => {
    let fileReader;

    const inputElem = useRef(null);
    const playerStates = GetPlayerStates();
    
    const handleFileRead = (rawSave) => (e) => {
        var data
        if (rawSave) {
            data = {'energy':100} // not technically how I'm importing, but it's ok.
        } else {
            const content = fileReader.result
            data = JSON.parse(content)
        }

        console.log(data)
        updatePlayerData(data, playerStates);
    }


    const handleFilePick = (e) => {
        var file = e.target.files[0]
        e.target.value = null
        fileReader = new FileReader()
        fileReader.onloadend = handleFileRead(file.type !== 'application/json');
        try {
            fileReader.readAsText(file)
        } catch{
            inputElem.current.value = null
        }

    }

    return (
        <div className="float-right mr-1">
            <input ref={inputElem} style={{ display: "none" }} type='file' id='savefileloader' onChange={e => handleFilePick(e)} />
            <button onClick={() => inputElem.current.click()}>Import save from file</button>
        </div>
    )
}

ImportSaveForm.propTypes = {}
export default ImportSaveForm;
```

So the idea is that when the user loads the first time, they should have `0` displayed. When they import the variable/state should be updated and the appropriate number (let's pretend it's `100`) will be displayed.

The problem: WhenI upload the file, the local storage is appropriately uploading and the `useEffect()` is running (I can see it in a `console.log`), but the text itself is *not* updating which makes me think I'm doing something wrong with the states. (Or maybe in the way I'm passing around the state that makes it not work?)

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong and/or what I can do to fix it? I'm at a loss what I'm doing wrong here.

**Edit:**
So an additional piece. When I do the following in the return:

```js
  return (
    <>
        {Epow} - {playerData['energy'][0]}
        <button
            onClick={e => 
                playerData['energy'][1](2)
            }
            >Text</button>
    </>
  )
}
```

and I click the button, it does properly update the display (and the local storage), but on refresh, it again goes back to showing 0. So somehow it's the interaction with the local storage that's causing issues.

**Edit 2:**
It was mentioned by Drew Reese that my hooks are bad so I've gone and run the ES Linter and fixed the hooks, but I'm still getting the same issues. I've edited the code above to reflect the changes I made.

Comment: Looks so much more complex than it should be. Take a look at Zustand library. it helps you manage complex states and is easy to use. it also has a middleware called "Persist" which allows you to save/load data in/from localStorage automatically.

Comment: I also have to add 2 points: 1. You don't need to check if the state is different before updating the state. React checks that under the hood and if it is the same value, it exits immediately. 2. inside your `useLocalStorageNumber` hook, the 2nd `useEffect`, you are setting the value inside your localStorage. keep in mind that the `setState` is async and won't change the state's value immediately. As a result, you are actually setting the `defaultValue` on the first render and override the previous data! The `setState` changes the value in the next render, not the current one.

Comment: I'll look at Zustand, thanks. For the second comment: (1) I thought that, but there were some times where it *wasnt* doing that. So I added it as a safety thing. (2) But it's not overriding the previous data (at least it's not overriding it in the local storage as the local storage has the correct number). I know that it's async, and maybe that's all that's happening? The async is making it override the previous state data?

Comment: I'm not sure. the code is too much to handle in my head. You can put a sample of your code on codesandbox and I will have a look

Comment: I looked at Zustand and it looks like they also mention having problems with setting global variables persistantly. It seems like the main issue is that I'm using nextjs which has both server and client side rendering which need to match. So it makes this type of behaviour a little harder to do. It might just be the case that I need to switch to react exclusively or find some other way in nextjs to persist data.

Comment: I don't know how you aren't saying or asking about tons of React hook usage issues/errors. Almost *all* of your hook calls are invalid. See React's [Rules of Hooks](https://react.dev/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning). I'm not sure it's even worth digging deeper until the initial code handling the hooks is resolved first.

Comment: I'll look at fixing those. Could it be the hooks that's causing this? I'm new to react so still trying to figure it all out.

Comment: From the linter/etc, the only hook issue/error I'm seeing is that I'm using `useLocalStorage` inside a for loop (since `useLocalStorage` has a state inside of it). What other errors are you talking about?
Also, if you can't use for loops, is there no way to initialise a lot of different variables based on an array? Do you need to do them manually instead?

Comment: I ran the linter and fixed all the hook issues, but it's still not working. I've updated the code above.